# How to get YEAR info from simple date string (YYYYMMDD) with SHELL SCRIPT?

Tags: string, shell, date, date-formatting

When I run this command to get year info from date '**20181102**' (format: *YYYYMMDD*), it works fine:

```
$ echo $(date --date="20181102" +"%Y")
2018
```

But when I try with this other date '**20181104**', I got an error:

```
$ echo $(date --date="20181104" +"%Y")
date: invalid date ‘20181104’
```

Is this any bug? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Both are working.

Comment: What is the output of `date --version` ?

Comment: date (GNU coreutils) 8.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU `date` utility is a little crude and keeps on misunderstanding the input string. For a good measure, try to always give `date` dates in `@`seconds since epoch or in one forms as in [man date](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date) like `"2004-02-29 16:21:42"`. (Unless you have [freebsd date](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?date) which has `-f` option.)

```
str=20181102
date --date="$(echo "$str" | cut -c 1-4)-$(echo "$str" | cut -c 5,6)-$(echo "$str" | cut -c 7,8) 00:00:00" +%Y
```

But really if you know that first 4 characters are year, why don't you just get first 4 characters?

```
str=20181102
echo "$str" | cut -c 1-4
```

Also note that doing `echo $(date ...)` is pointless. It's just `date ...`. The `echo` is not needed in any way.